# Working copy is locked

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-lock

I have created a new branch inside my most updated check out. Now am trying to remove it with 'undo add' but all it does is delete the files, keep the structure and folders, but gives me the message 'Working Copy locked'.

My Questions are:

a) Can I change my working copy?
b) If so, how do I change it back?
c) How do I remove this branch?

Comment: * http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cleanup.html

* http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html

Answer (score 1):

Note: Don't panic like me, just right click and click 'Clean-Up'. Sorted